# laravel how to validate array index and values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am submitting a single dimensional array of values to process on laravel 5.6

```
quantity[4]:11
quantity[2]:14
```

I have to validate both the index and the value, index should exits as stocks,id and value must be integer and minimum  1

I tried

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
       'quantity.*' => 'exists:stocks,id',
       'quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

but its validating only the values not index, please share your thoughts and comments.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Ross Laravel 5.6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can not see anywhere we can validate array index with default Laravel validation. That why we need to write a custom one.

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
       'quantity.*' => 'required|integer|min:1',
       'quantity' => [
           'required',
           'min:1', // make sure the input array is not empty <= edited
           'array',
           function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
               // index arr
               $ids = array_keys($value);
               // query to check if array keys is not valid
               $stockCntWithinArrIDs = StockModelFullNameWhaterver::whereIn('id', $ids)->count();
               if ($stockCntWithinArrIDs != count($ids))
                   return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');  // -> "quantity is invalid"
           }
       ],
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

The main point is compare stock count result when query `whereIn` (to reduce cost) their id with the array_keys of `quantity`. Because `quantity`'s index is exists in `stocks`, `$stockCntWithinArrIDs` has to equal to `count($ids)`, if not, there is at least one index is not as `stocks` id.

You can use `foreach ($ids)` then query the corresponding `stock` to see if my solution work. But PLEASE **DO NOT** use that solution on production env. :D

Hope this help!

**Edited:**

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: thanks, your solution ready for production env ? (just curious)

Comment: Actually, I've never seen input like that, I mean array indexes are existed in a table, so, the answer is no. But I wrote a lot of custom rules in my projects before. And I believe it can be used. :D